# can`t figure out error in my code, mixing jquery and razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am reading through a table in jquery and I am trying to pass the value to a method from a class.  I am trying to write the following but can`t figure what is wrong.

The error message is on the line if...:

> MvcUI\Views\Shared\employee.cshtml(170,81): error CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @
>   MvcUI\Views\Shared\employee.cshtml(170,83): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
>   MvcUI\Views\Shared\employee.cshtml(170,90): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
>   MvcUI\Views\Shared\employee.cshtml(170,103): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Help please.

```
 if($.trim($(this).find('td:first').text())!='')
            {    
             @{       

                if (MvcUI.Employee.ContainsName(@:$.trim($(this).find('td:first').text())))
                {
                    @:$($(this).find('td:first').html($(this).find('td:first').text() + "<br />Name");
                } 
             }                  
            }
```

Comment: .text() gets the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants. Maybe your TD contains HTML elements?

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery with Razor! I don't believe that can be done. You can use C#/VB (and the .NET framework), but not call jQuery methods in your Razor views, because this is run on your server. jQuery scripts should be used on the client.

Comment: please see error message as above

Comment: any example of how I can achiev the above please.

Answer (score 2):

There 2 way to do what you want:

1. Preload employer names into some js array
2. Use ajax to check if name is registred

I will describe the second way.

The JS code:

```
var tdText = jQuery.trim($(this).find('td:first').text());

if(tdText != '') {    
  jQuery.post
  (
     '/some_route/employers/checkname',
     {
        name = tdText
     },
     function(rsp) {
       if(rsp == 'true') {
         alert("name is registered"); //replace by your code
       }
       else
       {
         alert("name isn't registered"); //replace by your code
       }
     }
  );
}
```

The C# controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckName(string name)
{
  return Json(MvcUI.Employee.ContainsName(name));
}
```

Comment: I don`t think that`s the best idea as I am having some 10, 000 names and I am going through the first column of a table of 1000 lines

Comment: In this case, I think, you can send the list of names to check and receive the list of true/false. Some kind of bulk check. Anyway you can't mix the server side code with the client side code. IMHO the AJAX(web service or etc.) is most suitable for this solution.